# LINQ Quicksort is Unstable Except When Cascading

Tags: linq, sorting

On page 64 of "LINQ To Objects Using C# 4.0" (Tony Magennis) he states that LINQ's  quicksort ordering algorithm is unstable...

> ...although this is simply solved by
>   cascading the result into a ThenBy or
>   ThenByDescending operator.

Huh?  Why would cascading an unstable sortation into another sortation fix the result?  In fact, I'd say that isn't possible.  The original order, once passed through an unstable sort, is simply lost.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put simply, he's wrong. The Linq `OrderBy` *et al.* methods are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) as performing a stable sort:

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements that have the same key.

Comment: So if Magennis is wrong - the sort is stable - then he evidently is wrong for saying it is a quicksort.  A quicksort is inherently unstable.  This raises the question: if it isn't a quicksort, then what is it?

Answer (score 5):

Unstable sort means that a chain of `x.OrderBy(...).OrderBy(...)` calls will only reliably sort according to the final criterion. `x.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` explicitly captures knowledge of the previous sort order when applying the new sort order. I believe it does this by calling [`IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>.CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548559%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), though I'm not 100% sure of this.

EDIT: Just to be clear, when I say, "captures the knowledge..." I don't mean to suggest that the first OrderBy performs a sort, and somehow the second one knows what it did. Remember that `OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, which doesn't perform any work at all until someone tries to consume the elements. In this scenario, it will never perform the sort, since `ThenBy`, using knowledge of how `OrderBy` *would* have sorted, constructs a brand new sorter that applies both sort orderings in the expected manner and in a single step.

It has been pointed out that Magennis is wrong on the unstable sort thing. The above description is still valid, however.

Comment: Ah, I see... he's saying instead of `x.OrderBy(a => a.LastName).OrderBy(a => a.FirstName)` you should do `x.OrderBy(a => a.LastName).ThenBy(a => a.FirstName)`. That makes more sense than my answer :)

Comment: The "stability" of a sort is a comp-sci concept that has nothing to do with "capturing the knowledge of the prior sort."  It seems Magennis should not have used the designation "unstable sort."

Comment: Well, if LINQ uses unstable sort, then "unstable sort" is the correct designator. Of course, he could be wrong, but assuming he isn't, I've amended the answer to perhaps clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

He's saying if do, say `orderby LastName` only then anybody with the same last name will be sorted in an unpredictable order. So if you combine it with, say `orderby LastName, FirstName` you can make the order predictable again (except for people with the same first *and* last name of course).

At least, that's what I would assume.