# What Sorting Algorithm Is Used By LINQ "OrderBy"?

Tags: linq, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Evidently LINQ's "OrderBy" had originally been specified as unstable, but by the time of Orca it was specified as stable.  Not all documentation has been updated accordingly - consider these links:

- [Jon Skeet on OrderBy stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209935/orderby-and-orderbydescending-are-stable)
- [Troy Magennis on OrderBy stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786930/linq-quicksort-is-unstable-except-when-cascading)

But if LINQ's OrderBy is now "stable," then it means it is not using a quicksort (which is inherently unstable) even though some documentation (e.g. Troy's book) says it is.  So my question is: if not quicksort, then what is the actual algorithm LINQ's orderBy is using?

Comment: Stictly, Linq's `OrderBy` is not specified for stability. `Enumerable.OrderBy` is specified as stable, other providers are free to also offer that promise but may not. Doing so may be impossible or very expensive (consider the impact it would have on parallelisation in terms of p-linq for example) or relatively cheap, which is a big influence on what providers will do.

Comment: A very related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148074/465053).

Comment: would it be bad to tag this [c#]? or at least [.net]? I missed this question because I begin all my queries with [c#] (unless I happen to be doing javascript that day)...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

For LINQ to Objects, it's a stable quicksort that is used. For any other kind of LINQ, it's left to the underlying implementation.

Comment: If I have an object referenced as only `IEnumerable<Foo>` how does Linq know if it's Linq-to-Objects or something else?

Comment: IEnumerable is always Linq to objects (vs IQueryable which is Linq to whatever else)

Comment: @Dai IEnumerable<T> is an interface, so it actually depends of what type has the underlying collection (I dont agree with @John). For instance, List<T> implements IEnumerable<T>, and you could have a List<T> declared as IEnumerable<T>. If you perform an order by on this list, the Linq-to-objects provider is used. On the other hand. DbSet<T> also implements IEnumerable<T>. If you perform an order by on this DbSet, even if it is declared as an IEnumerable, Linq-to-sql provider will be used. If you wanted to use linq-to-objects on a dbset, you could do dbset.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(lambda)

Comment: @DanielGarcíaRubio DbSet does not directly implement IEnumerable, it implements IQueryable, which in turn always implements IEnumerable. So i dont completely understand why you do not agree with John, as what he said is correct.

Answer (score 42):

Boot up reflector, open to System.Linq.EnumerableSorter reveals that Linq2Objects uses the quick sort

Comment: +1 for looking it up. But a simple test shows no n^2 growth in time consumption as elements number of reverse sorted List of int increases, as it should be according to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort I tried 1k and 1M elements worst-case - time consumption increased only about 50 times

Comment: @EvAlex Quicksort doesn't run in quadratic time.  Well, it can, but that's the upper bound and rare.  If it were theta(n**2) everyone would just use mergesort.

Comment: Now .NET core is opened to everyone :) Why don't you have a closer look? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1395017e067e5a34

Answer (score 16):

Quicksort is used, but the reason why it is stable is because the indices of each pair of elements are compared if all the keys test equal.

In other words, you can make any quicksort stable by including in the comparator function a comparison of the original indices of the two elements as a fallback.

Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1395017e067e5a34

Comment: Have been looking for a while for the open source link, thanks

Comment: In theory, you could stabilise any sorting algorithm by including the original indices in the comparator.  The challenge is figuring out the best data structure to use to keep track of these original indices.

Answer (score 3):

I am under the understanding that `OrderBy` gets translated into SQL that performs the sort on the Database.  At least in the case of LINQ to SQL

Comment: Yes, but that's only true for Linq to SQL and other database Linq providers. Linq is not just an ORM... (Linq to Objects, Linq to XML...)