# Sorting multiple arrays, based on the first array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, quicksort

Currently I'm working on a project where I'm required to sort a total of 6 arrays.

I've managed to sort the arrays individually using a quicksort, however, I'm just wondering if there is a way to sort 1 array and reflect that on the order of elements in the other arrays. For example, if I sort my date array to an ascending  order, I want the other arrays to still match up with the dates in respect to the new order.

If possible, could this still be done through a quick sort?

Comment: There probably is a way, but it seems a much better approach to your problem is to have a single array of objects, and sort the 1 array by their date

Comment: There is `Array.Sort` which lets you sort an array by a keys array.

Comment: It's easier to do if you pack all the data of the 6 arrays in a single structure (its own class or a Tuple) and give your QuickSort function a lambda or `Func` to sort by, then split the result after sorting.

Answer (score 3):

I think the more appropriate option will be to create a new class with all different 6 kind of properties

```
public class myClass
{
    public DateTime date{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
    //....
}
```

Then create a single array/list of that class.

```
public List<myClass> arrData;
```

Now you can sort that array based on any of your desired property and it will keep the order as per your requirements

```
arrData.OrderBy(x => x.name)
```

You can replace x.name with any of your myClass property.

This approach makes your code clean and easy to manage as well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like LINQ uses the quick sort algorithm for the `OrderBy` method (see [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792105/1937249)).
Something like this should take care of it for you:

```
DateTime[] datesOfBirth = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(1955, 10, 28), new DateTime(1955, 2, 24) };
String[] firstNames = new String[] { "William", "Steve" };
String[] lastNames = new String[] { "Gates", "Jobs" };

var people = 
    datesOfBirth
    .Select((_, i) => new 
        { 
            DateOfBirth = datesOfBirth[i],
            FirstName = firstNames[i],
            LastName = lastNames[i]
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.DateOfBirth)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a setup something like this:

```
DateTime [] dates;
string [] names;
int [] ids;
//...etc
```

Consider instead to condense your data into a single object, then have a single array of that object:

```
public class MyObject 
{
    DateTime date { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    int id { get; set; }
}
```

Now you will only have 1 array:

```
MyObject [] objects;
```

And you can sort the whole collection of objects by their date:

```
objects.Sort((a, b) => a.date.CompareTo(b.date));
```

Also consider using Lists rather than straight arrays, as the use case for using vanilla arrays in c# is very small:

```
List<MyObject> objects;
```

Comment: @HaseebAsif years of programming will cause that =P

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i've been busy >.< ok this looks promising, however will this still work if I applied this to a custom quick sort method instead of the inbuilt .Sort? For this project i'm not allowed to use in-built sorting mechanisms since I will need to calculate the efficiency of my program...that and regulations >.>

Comment: @PTR01 I don't see why not, as long as your custom quick sort knows to pull the date value off the object