# Explain the following results I got from a performance test of OrderBy

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting

I've read other SO posts on the complexity of LINQ's OrderBy function such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792074/what-sorting-algorithm-is-used-by-linq-orderby) and so I'm wondering why the following test I made

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] avgs = new double[100];
        int tests_per_size = 1000; 
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Stopwatch stpw = new Stopwatch();
        for(int i = 1; i <= avgs.Length; ++i)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            int[] arr = new int[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < tests_per_size; ++j)
            {

                for(int k = 0; k < arr.Length; ++k)
                    arr[k] = rnd.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
                stpw.Start();
                var slist = arr.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();   
                stpw.Stop();
                sum += stpw.ElapsedTicks;
            }
            avgs[i-1] = sum / (double)tests_per_size;
        }
        foreach(var t in avgs)
            Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

gave me the following results

```
15076,327
17261,652
19528,579
21993,155
24674,83
26927,163
29332,665
32018,45
35143,727
38955,111
43188,589
47605,542
52243,952
57166,918
63454,059
70261,749
75997,727
82249,885
88953,873
96958,163
104520,145
112432,1
120746,806
129694,464
138588,981
148007,988
157616,249
167493,94
177748,543
188904,677
200761,557
212235,986
225877,753
239173,783
252288,474
265901,092
279629,762
294529,835
309429,827
326944,916
343254,802
361306,427
378797,508
395831,364
413546,694
431166,319
449165,652
467562,618
487180,928
505969,021
525013,641
544555,831
564859,752
585357,237
606849,766
628464,581
651009,432
673865,517
697340,663
720709,903
744837,668
769024,863
793921,415
819441,534
845185,441
873421,004
901587,713
928140,083
955403,824
983023,284
1011295,028
1040868,504
1070366,748
1100416,455
1131158,53
1162260,852
1193641,253
1225165,58
1257410,12
1289450,658
1322668,533
1358718,074
1400162,62
1440996,876
1483102,815
1531781,127
1581157,377
1627831,867
1673969,553
1713026,287
1750012,667
1787497,946
1825893,268
1864184,643
1902912,621
1942420,978
1982395,399
2023052,109
2063803,114
2106027,85
```

Notice how it approximately doubles every 10 numbers.

Comment: You're starting, then stopping the stopwatch, then you grab the current elapsed value, then you reuse the same stopwatch without resetting? This will make the elapsed values accumulate faster. Try either resetting the stopwatch inside the inner loop or only read the final elapsed value outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, you're never `Restart`ing your stopwatch, so the timings you're seeing are accumulative. If you change your `Start()` call to `Restart()` you'll get some saner values.

Another important point to make is that you're only testing arrays up to a size of 100, which is not nearly enough to clearly see the algorithm's asymptotic behavior.

Finally, note that you're not just testing `OrderBy()`: you're also testing `ToList()`. The effect won't be huge, but a good test should isolate the parts that you're really interested in.