C# IEnumerable.ElementAt() acting unexpectedly on an OrderedEnumerable
During the 5th task of this years Advent of Code, I stumbled across this weird behavior:
If you order an enumerable with a comparator that doesn't check for transitive comparison, the ElementAt method returns a different ordering than the actual enumeration (apart from ElementAt(0), this is redirected to First(), which respects the ordering).
Example code to try it out for yourself (.NET 8.0):
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        List<int> original = [2, 3, 1];
        var sorted = original.Order(new MyComparer());
        Assert.Equal("1,2,3", string.Join(',', sorted));    // succeeds, so it is sorted correctly, right? (nope)
        var enumerator = sorted.GetEnumerator();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            Assert.Equal(i, enumerator.Current);    // succeeds as well
        }
        Assert.Equal(1, sorted.First());        // succeeds
        Assert.Equal(1, sorted.ElementAt(0));   // succeeds
        Assert.Equal(2, sorted.ElementAt(1));   // fails, is actually 3
        Assert.Equal(3, sorted.ElementAt(2));   // fails, is actually 1 again???
    }

    private class MyComparer() : IComparer<int>
    {

        public int Compare(int left, int right)
        {
            if (left == 1 && right == 2) return -1;
            else if (left == 2 && right == 3) return -1;
            else if (left == 3 && right == 2) return 1;
            else if (left == 2 && right == 1) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    }
}

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?
Also, is this incorrect behavior or does this just fall under the nose demon rule?

To be clear: I am aware that the comparer says 1 is equal to 3. What I'm concerned about is that the behavior is now not consistent any more.

How would your method MyComparer.Compare() look if you had to sort 100 numbers? Million numbers? Current version is a source of mess.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30092163/17034

The requirement that comparers be transitive -- as well as reflexive and antisymmetric -- is documented in IComparable.CompareTo(T) Method: Notes to Implementers.  And, in general, sorting algorithms do require comparers that satisfy those requirements to behave properly, see Is transitivity required for a sorting algorithm.  So you do appear to be hitting some undefined behavior, which you can fix by making your comparer transitive.

If you don't want to have a transitive comparer, you may need to look into topological sort algorithms.  See e.g. Topological sort with support for cyclic dependencies or Topological Sorting using LINQ.  Does that answer your question?

Looking a bit further, it seems that Order().ElementAt() has an optimization where a partial quick sort is done to sort just the required number of elements.  See OrderedEnumerable.PartialQuickSort(), OrderedEnumerable.SpeedOpt.cs ...

... and the check for IPartition<TSource> inside ElementAtt().  That, combined with the undefined sorting behavior due to the lack of transitivity, likely explains your surprising results.

I think the internal implementation of sorted.ElementAt() (for indexes >0) might end up at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/bf44aaab18b8f8281264b0ccdd47f8a621514aa2/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs#L576 to attempt to locate the correct element without actually sorting anything.

@dbc I wasn't looking for a way to do this correctly, but thank you, those references are still very interesting!

@dbc Also, you seem to be right about the partial quicksort. If you wanna post that as an answer, I would mark that as accepted.

Just an unrelated note: ".NET Framework 8" isn't a thing. .NET Framework stopped at version 4.8.1. ".NET" (which is a rebranding of the earlier ".NET Core") started at version 5. So .NET 8 is just ".NET 8".

You're hitting undefined behavior here.  The requirement that comparers be transitive -- as well as reflexive and antisymmetric -- is documented in IComparable<T>.CompareTo(T) Method: Notes to Implementers:

If A.CompareTo(B) returns a value x that is not equal to zero, and B.CompareTo(C) returns a value y of the same sign as x, then A.CompareTo(C) is required to return a value of the same sign as x and y.

And, in general, all comparison sorting algorithms do require comparison functions that are total which includes transitivity.  LINQ's Order() and OrderBy() use a stable quicksort which is a type of comparison sort; by violating the requirement for transitivity in your comparer you will get unpredictable results from your orderings.
But as to why sorted.ToList()[1] produces a different result than sorted.ElementAt(1), that appears to fall out of an optimization made by MSFT.  Order() uses deferred execution so the ordering is not evaluated until the query is enumerated - then is re-evaluated every time the query is enumerated.  But a review of the source code indicates that, when Order() (or OrderBy()) are combined with ElementAt(i), LINQ doesn't sort the entire enumerable.  It just sorts enough to determine the ith element using a partial quicksort quickselect algorithm which also requires transitivity.  And since a slightly different algorithm is used, it's not surprising that its undefined behavior differs from the undefined behavior of the full sort.
If you don't want to have a transitive comparer, you may need to look into topological sort algorithms.  See e.g.

Topological sort with support for cyclic dependencies
Topological Sorting using LINQ

